# Attempting to JIT compile method 'Akavache.Sqlite3.Registrations:Register (Splat.IMutableDependencyResolver)' while running in aot-only mode

Tags: akavache

- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.Forms 3.6
- akavache v6.4.1

```
The type initializer for 'Akavache.BlobCache' threw an exception.
Attempting to JIT compile method 'Akavache.Sqlite3.Registrations:Register (Splat.IMutableDependencyResolver)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information.
```

when debug run on actual device, error above are counter as soon as below code are called

```
Akavache.Registrations.Start("AppName");
```

tried to execute in

- AppDelegate.cs before/after Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
- PCL library App.cs OnStart()

all throw same error

any idea why will invoke JIT ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix with splat v7.1, akavache is being updated to use it in this PR https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/pull/472

Also worth noting the following bug https://github.com/reactiveui/splat/issues/292

Comment: any idea to fix this?
tried 

- downgrade the ReactiveUI to 9.11.3 which reference Splat 6.1.7
- install nuget Splat 6.1.7 manually

both not working -_-

Answer (score 0):

- akavache v6.4.1
- ReactiveUI 9.11.3
- install of akavache to platform project is not required like some people mentioned
- clean solution (important)

and problem solved

thanks @Glenn Watson